# Techniques to remove dependencies?

Tags: c#, class, dependencies

Scenario:

An **event** is raised in class A that needs to be handled by a **method** in class B. (currently via a delegate)
The data that gets passed from the **event** to the **method** is currently wrapped in class C.
This obviously requires class B to be dependent on class C.

Is there any techniques/refactoring that i can perform in order to remove this dependecy?
*e.g. unrolling the data back to simple primitive data types and passing them directly.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

unrolling to primitives would work, but be certain that you really do want to remove this dependency. It is perfectly valid for classes A and B to both depend on C if C is a bridge between them, or if C feeds both of them, etc.

unrolling to primitives removes a compilation dependency, but not a data dependency, and may actually be "denormalizing" the design by removing an entity (class C) which is logicially required

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Steven Lowe; The dependency probably is valid.  The only alternative I can offer is to depend on an interface instead of an actual class, but it pretty much boils down to the same thing.

Comment: Always code to an interface, depending onto the interface instead of the actual implementation improves overall flexibility and testability.

Answer (score 0):

As most others have said, the dependency on C is probably valid.

However, if depending on C gives you problems, it might be because C is too complicated or has too many dependencies on its own.

If class C is passed in an event, it should probably be a POCO class with no dependencies of its own, so you might want to consider refactoring that.

If C has complicated methods of its own, it is a good bet that they actually belong on class A.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at Dependency Injection frameworks like [Structuremap](http://structuremap.sourceforge.net/Default.htm) to at least centralize these dependencies and make them configurable? I haven't tried it with events/delegate types, but it's a great tool if you're passing a lot of custom types/interfaces around your layers.

Answer (score -2):

You could serialize to XML, and than read the XML directly via XPATH (without deserializing)